# How do I get all properties from an arbitrary Kotlin object?

Tags: kotlin, reflection

This is another Kotlin oddity I've run into.

I had this code:

```kotlin
TableCharsets::class.declaredMemberProperties.asSequence()
    .map { p -> p.get(TableCharsets) }
```

and it worked fine.

Then I wanted to do it for more than one object in a loop. So I thought I could write this:

```kotlin
sequenceOf(TableCharsets, Iso2022Charsets, EucCharsets, ShiftJisCharsets).forEach { obj ->
    obj::class.declaredMemberProperties.asSequence()
        .map { p -> p.get(obj) }
}
```

But the compiler complains about the call to `p.get(obj)`.

And indeed, if I write this:

```kotlin
val obj = TableCharsets
obj::class.declaredMemberProperties.asSequence()
    .map { p -> p.get(obj) }
```

This gives the same error. Apparently `p.get(R)` takes `Nothing`, so there is no possible object I can pass in which would be acceptable.

Thinking that maybe I lost the type of the object somehow, I tried extracting to a function so that it had a known but generic type:

```kotlin
fun <T: Any> extract(obj: T): Sequence<Any> {
    obj::class.declaredMemberProperties.asSequence()
        .map { p -> p.get(obj) }
}
```

Again, I get the error that `p.get(R)` only takes `Nothing`, and won't let me pass in a `T`.

When I hover over `declaredMemberProperties`, IDEA says that it returns a `Collection<KProperty<T, *>>`, but somehow the property `p` inside my lambda is a `KProperty1<out Any, *>`, so that's surely the problem. But it makes no sense to me right now how it is getting that type.

How can I make this work?

Comment: One question though, *why* would you list the values of all properties of an arbitrary Kotlin object?

Comment: As Joffrey indicates, this isn't something you'd generally want to do in Kotlin.  Reflection is a code smell; it's necessary for things like frameworks, plug-ins, and build tools; but it's slow, awkward, fragile, insecure, and for general application coding there's very often a better approach.  Folks who come from dynamic/weakly-typed languages might naturally gravitate towards it — but a strongly-typed OO language like Kotlin provides better tools for most purposes.

Comment: @Joffrey I'm reluctant to just move all the constants into the one object, because having them in separate objects makes it easier to find them.

Comment: @gidds is there a better way to structure this code then? I don't really want to list all my charsets twice - once to have them as convenient constants, and then a second time in a giant map just to have a map of them to list them or look them up by name or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

When we use `obj::class` then it is unknown at the compile time, what exactly is the type of `obj`. We only know its upper bounds, but we don't know the specific type. Therefore, we don't know who is the owner of acquired members and what object do we have to use to access them. For this reason by default `obj::class` returns `KClass<out MyType>` which means we can't pass any owner object to it.

Unfortunately, the compiler is not smart enough to recognize that you acquired `KClass` from exactly the same object that you then use to access members. I believe in that case the operation is safe to do and you can force the compiler to allow it by making an unchecked cast:

```kotlin
(obj::class as KClass<T>).declaredMemberProperties
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference is right at the start actually. `TableCharsets::class` is of type `KClass<TableCharsets>` - it's exactly that class. However, it's different when the object instance is extracted to a variable like this:

```kotlin
val obj = TableCharsets
val kClass = obj::class
```

Here `obj` is an instance of the class `TableCharsets`, and its static type is `TableCharsets`. However when calling `::class` on it, the compiler can only be sure that it's `TableCharsets` OR a *subclass* of `TableCharsets`, so the class instance you get is of type `KClass<out TableCharsets>`.

This means that when iterating the properties, you cannot know that `obj` will be sufficient to satisfy the argument of `get`. Effectively, you're trying to pass an `out`-only type in an `in` position (the argument of `get`).

You can see the problem more clearly here:

```kotlin
val obj: Parent = Child()
val kClass: KClass<out Parent> = obj::class // actually KClass<Child>
kClass.declaredMemberProperties.asSequence()
    .map { p -> p.get(Parent()) } // shouldn't accept a Parent instance here
```

`Parent()` is obviously not acceptable as input, and from the compiler's point of view `obj` is also just of `Parent` type, and thus not acceptable as input, even though it's the object you initially got the `KClass` from (the compiler doesn't realize that)

Comment: I guess it's doubly nasty that when I hover over `::class` in IDEA, it says nothing about what it returns. I didn't even suspect that it might be the culprit.